# how to remove white space on the top

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am trying to create top jumbotron above the navbar in materializecss
Here is my code for template.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes.css"/>

  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="top">
    <h1>Hello Sykox</h1>
</div>


<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
  <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and here is code for includes.css

```
.top {
height: 170px;
background-color: #ef9a9a;
margin: 0px;
```

}

unfortunately there appears white space on extreme top and it doesn't goes away even with margin: 0px; or margin-top:0px;

[image]

so any idea how to remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
  <style>
    html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, div {
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .top {
      padding: 0;
      height: 170px;
      background-color: #ef9a9a;
      margin: 0px;
    }
  </style>

  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="top">
    <h1>Hello Sykox</h1>
</div>


<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
  <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Explaination :
Each browser has it's own preferences, for example when I tried on Chrome, the margin was set to 8 px, to override the browser setting, you need to add this into your css :

```
html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, div {
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Worked like Charm... thank You So much... @budiantoip

Comment: @budiantoip would you mind explaining why my answer didn't work?

Comment: Wait, let me try yours

Comment: @VickyGonsalves check here. https://jsfiddle.net/rbcz3unv/1/. h1 tag is set as  `margin: 2.1rem 0 1.68rem;` by `materialize.min.css` it will override `*` css

Comment: Well, it's already answered. Did you try it before answering? I did it, that's why my answer took longer than yours. Anyway, let's keep up helping people :)

Answer (score 1):

It is because your h1 tag taking margin.

`materialize.min.css` set `h1` tag as `margin: 2.1rem 0 1.68rem;`

Use following solve your issue.

```
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbcz3unv/)**

Answer (score 1):

Add a css reset like this:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, caption {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it conflict if i want to add padding to some element later... or then i should use !important;

Comment: It wouldn't. It will just initialize a fresh palette.